# Nim game real life applications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

I've learned how to prove and apply the Nim game strategy in discrete mathematics, but I was wondering if there is any real life examples and application for this theory. I searched online and didn't find much, does anyone know any of its applications?

Thanks!